# Como passar datas em Java para um banco de dados?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, string, datetime

Estou tentando passar uma data no formato `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"` para o banco de dados para isso estou usando o `Date()` e o `SimpleDateFormat()`, porém ele me retorna uma *string*. Tem alguma forma dele me retornar um date ou se há alguma conversão para tal?

Comment: Tem jeito mas depende do que você precisa. Talvez o seu problema é não usar apenas o `Date()`. Tem quer ver o que seu banco de dados está esperando. Você não deu detalhes de como está fazendo, não colocou código. `SimpleDateFormat()` é para montar *strings* mesmo e não para formatar datas, até porque datas não possuem formato, datas são datas. Só textos que mostram datas é que possuem formato. Em uma data o que importa é o valor contido nela e não a forma como ela é apresentada.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado pela dica cara, estava olhando o banco que é de um projeto feito por terceiros e ele esperava datetime, então resolvi o problema apenas mudando de Date() para Timestamp().

Comment: Vou responder para não deixar sem resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem jeito mas depende do que você precisa. Tem quer ver o que seu banco de dados está esperando. Está mandando o dado em um tipo diferente do esperado pelo banco de dados. Então precisa descobrir qual é o tipo esperado e mandar desta forma.

[`SimpleDateFormat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) é para montar *strings* mesmo e não para formatar datas, até porque datas não possuem formato, datas são datas. Só textos que mostram datas é que possuem formato. Em uma data o que importa é o valor contido nela e não a forma como ela é apresentada.

De fato o autor descobriu que precisava usar `Timestamp()`.